# Servlet 3.0 annotations <welcome-file>

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servletconfig

Is it possible to set welcome-file tag from standard web.xml file by servlet 3.0 annotation ?

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>PageName.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I'd be curious how you would annotate a JSP/HTML file to be the `welcome-file`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not such annotation at the moment. Servlet 3.0 annotations are InitParam, ServletFilter, WebServlet, WebServletContextListener, there's nothin for the welcome files in there.

Comment: yes.. looks like it`s only in proposal currently
http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315