# Make Localhost/projectName homepage url

Tags: java, jsp

I'm not sure how to start on this, but I currently have a simple application that has a home page url of

```
localhost:8080/projectName/homePage.jsp
```

However, I'd like it so that

```
localhost:8080/projectName/
```

OR

```
localhost:8080/projectName
```

sends me to the homePage.jsp.

I've read about an index.jsp that was created by eclipse in other projects, but it seems like that hasn't been done for me - do I need to create this? I'm not using a web.xml, and am instead relying on @WebServlet to do wiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways to do this.
1. Add an entry in web.xml as follows

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>homepage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

2. create an index.jsp file in your WebContent folder and forward the request to homePage.jsp

Answer (score 0):

According to the following post there is no such way possible with annotation:

[Servlet 3.0 annotations <welcome-file>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540549/servlet-3-0-annotations-welcome-file)